# Find all documents where ref ID is in array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have *CourseSchema*, and inside it, I have:

```
teachers: [{
    id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Teacher"
    },
    username: String
}]
```

Now I want to find all Courses for one Teacher. I imagined doing something like this:

```
Course.find().where("teachers.id").equals(user._id).exec(function(err, courses) {};
```

But this always returns empty array []. Now, my guess is it's because *teachers* field is an array, not just a string. So is there an alternative for .where() for arrays?

Also, do I need to .populate() all courses and then search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with your query inside `find()` instead of `where().equals()`. You don't really need to populate all courses just to find courses of a teacher.

```
Course.find({"teachers.id" : user._id}, function (err, courses) {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   // Your functions
});
```

Comment: I got it to work with "teachers._id" (even tho I defined in Schema "id"). Even my query works with "teachers._id"